# Creating Layout for ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have to developed one expandablelistview.here if i have to run the program means it is worked successfully...but i have faced one problem...
               The problem is if i have to click first group means the first group childrens all are displayed and also simply displayed second group children space.... Same problem is occurred here also.if i have to  click second group means simply displayed first group children space afterthat displayed second group childrens...why this error is came here.please refer my code and give me solutions.please refer my screenshot that time you are clearly understood my question.
[image]
please help me...what problem is here.why space is occurred here...please help me friends.

Below code is my android-layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/payment_method1"
     android:paddingLeft="5px"
     android:textSize="15dip"

    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/payment_method"
     android:paddingLeft="75px"
     android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/total1"

     android:paddingLeft="5px"
     android:textSize="15dip"

    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       <TextView
    android:id="@+id/total"

     android:paddingLeft="65px"
     android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/firstname1"
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
     android:textSize="15dip"

    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
     <TextView
     android:id="@+id/firstname"
    android:paddingLeft="65px"
     android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView
     android:id="@+id/lastname1"
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
     android:textSize="15dip"

    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/lastname"
    android:paddingLeft="65px"
     android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution for this after some changes in my android layout file.